# Prestashop Open Graph Tags

Tags: prestashop, facebook-opengraph

One of the core modules of Prestashop is the **socialsharing** module. It is put together without any regard for valid OGP tags on various page types within Presta such as the CMS pages. Read the backstory at https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/436582-invalid-ogp-tags-in-module-socialsharings-hook-header-view/

My question would be if trying to setup smarty conditionals, how could I express cases that detect CMS, Product Page, Product Category, Specials, Featured, etc?

Comment: I've run into the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: The module was updated. It doesn't address conditionals, still.

Answer (score 0):

The developers fixed most of the issues with Presta Forge Issue **[NM-367](http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/NM-367)**. It should be available as a module update in PrestaShop version **1.6.0.14**

It does not address conditionals in my original question.